# The difference made by ".0" in double calculation

Tags: java, double

In the calculation of double numbers, what's the difference between, say, 6.0 and 6?
Because when I was solving a problem on online judge, the expression

```
estimatedPI = Math.sqrt(6*a/b);
```

got "Wrong answer" on OJ, while

```
estimatedPI = Math.sqrt(6.0*a/b);
```

got "Accepted" on OJ.

For the output, because I used

```
String result;
result = String.format("%.6f\n",estimatedPI);
System.out.print(result);
```

so the output looks exactly the same, with six digits after decimal point.

The estimatedPI is declared double and a,b declared int.

So why 6.0 got "Accepted" and 6 got "Wrong answer"?  What would be the difference here?

Thanks.

Edit: Noted of duplicated questions.

Answer (score 1):

`6.0` is a `double`. `6` is an `int`.

If `a` and `b` are also `int`s, then `6*a/b` is *not* a "double calculation" - it will be done using `int` arithmetic.

When you mix `double`s and `int`s in a binary mathematical operation, the int is converted to a double and then the operation is done using double arithmetic. So `6.0*a` does a double multiplication (converting `a` to double first), resulting in a double. Then `(the result of that)/b` also does a double division (converting `b` to double first).

Answer (score 0):

The .0 is an indicator to the compiler that the constant is a floating point number rather than an integer. Your expression `6 * a / b` will be treated as an integer expression.